# Using Regular expression how to check the Empty value in my MVC2 validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Can any body tell me how to check the Emppty string using Regularexpression

```
[RegularExpression(@"\b(0?[0-9][0-9][0-9])\b", ErrorMessage = "BEI Code should be Only three Chracter Length!")]
```

I need to look for Empty string also in this validation

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not check for the empty string using a `Required` validation attribute alongside your `RegularExpression` attribute?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"\b(0?[0-9][0-9][0-9])\b", 
                  ErrorMessage = "BEI Code should be Only three Chracter Length!")]
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie, yes I tried that but some reason my Required filed is not working properly.. Instead of This field is required I am getting the message for Empty '{PropertyName}' should not be Empty.. I dont know why I am getting this message?